# Поиск значений в базе в дубликатах

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы:
1 - таблица (orders) с заказами с колонками order_id, order_status, order_descr(опционально)
2 - таблица (products) с продуктами с колонками order_id, product_id

Нужно сделать выборку по product id = 1234(А) и 7345(Б). То есть в результате показал заказы, которые содержат и продукт А и продукт Б, ну и желательно показал заказы в которых только эти продукты и ничего более.
Я пробовал делать поиск в дубликатах, но моих знаний для этого недостаточно. Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

Comment: Это называется "реляционное деление".

Answer (score 0):

Типовое решение:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING MAX(product_id = 1234) -- есть хотя бы один 
   AND MAX(product_id = 5678) -- есть хотя бы один 
   AND NOT MAX(product_id NOT IN (1234, 5678)) -- нет других
```

Если надо только наличие, то проще:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
WHERE product_id IN (1234, 5678)
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) = 2
```

PS. Предполагается, что `product_id` определён как NOT NULL.

Comment: там 2 таблицы, ваше решение не работает первая таблица orders, вторая products

Comment: @durqan Вторая таблица - с заказами - для задачи нафиг не нужна. Нужна только таблица продуктов.

Comment: Код не работает, результат пустота

Comment: @durqan Делайте fiddle - покажу. Ну или хотя бы выкладывайте CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с тест-данными и требуемый ответ для них.